# Python Unable to execute powershell script

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, subprocess

I have been trying to execute a powershell script from my main python program. The script has been tested and works directly through powershell. This however isn't the case when I launch a process to execute it in python.

I have tried multiple methods, ensured powershell has no execution policy restricting me (unrestricted). I have also tried a batch file which worked however when I used python to execute the batch file it errors

```py
com = os.path.join( ".", 'test2.ps1 -in "C:','Users','kbrab','Desktop','Test','test.csv" -out "C:','Users','kbrab','Desktop','Test','OSReport.xlsx"')
print(com)
p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'unrestricted',
              com],stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

The com string has correct paths and is printed as such:

.\test2.ps1 -in "C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\Test\test.csv" -out "C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\Test\OSReport.xlsx"

Figured I would also add powershell script:

```bsh
param([string]$in = "in", [string]$out = "out")
Import-Module ImportExcel
Write-Host "Arg: $in"
Write-Host "Arg: $out"

Import-CSV $in | Export-Excel $out `
    -IncludePivotTable `
    -PivotRows 'BName' `
    -PivotData @{'MEMBERNBR'='count'}
```

**The error message is:**

> ```
> (None, b"Export-Excel : The term 'Export-Excel' is not recognized as the name of a 
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\Test\test2.ps1:5 char:18
> + Import-CSV $in | Export-Excel $out `
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Export-Excel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException")
> ```

The powershell script on its own imports a csv then exports a pivot table, it works correctly when executed directly through powershell.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

**Update 1**

Second error after adding import to powershell script

> ```
> (None, b"Import-Module : The specified module 'ImportExcel' was not loaded because no 
> valid module file was found in any module directory.
> At C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\Test\test2.ps1:2 char:1
> + Import-Module ImportExcel
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (ImportExcel:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
>
> Export-Excel : The term 'Export-Excel' is not recognized as the name of a 
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At C:\Users\kbrab\Desktop\Test\test2.ps1:6 char:18
> + Import-CSV $in | Export-Excel $out `
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Export-Excel:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException")
> ```

**Tested on powershell alone and still worked**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export-Excel is a cmdlet from the `ImportExcel` powershell module. The error message shows that it isn't finding that so it appears to be executing the Powershell script correctly but the Powershell script isn't importing that module and the cmdlet isn't being found.

Make sure that `Import-Module ImportExcel` is at the top of your PowerShell script.

Comment: I got another error after adding the import module to top of ps1 script

Comment: Do you have the `ImportExcel` module installed on the machine you are running the Python and Powershell programs on?

Comment: Yes it is installed, if it was not installed then running the ps1 script through powershell (not python) wouldn't have worked

Comment: @KeenanB: Are you running with the same user identity in both cases? Try passing the full path to the module directory to  `Import-Module`.

Comment: Both scripts are located in the same directory, on my local machine so they must be using the same identity?

Comment: What I am failing to understand is how this module's imports is working when I run from powershell,but when I open powershell from python's subprocess and run the same command suddenly the imports arent recognized?

Comment: @KeenanB I didn’t see it in the code snippet above but you don’t have any additional parameters like “-NoProfile” executing in the subprocess right? Also, what is the CWD for the Python script? Maybe changing that with os.chdir() would help?

Comment: The CWD is the same directory as the powershell script, and no there is not any parameters such as -NoProfile

Comment: If you do `get-module importexcel | select path` in Powershell it should output the location of where the ImportExcel module is located. Make sure that folder (or one of the sub folders like `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` is in your PATH. You can check your path with `$env:path.split(';')`

Comment: After adding the import excel to every path that exists ($env:path.split(';')), it works!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked!

As a possible follow up step I would write a small PowerShell script that outputs the value of $env:path and run that script from Python to see what it outputs. It is probably worth it to find out which folder ImportExcel is being read from so you don't have the module duplicated all over the place in case you need to update it in the future.

Comment: Would you please consider marking this as the answer if it was beneficial to you?